# Using a JavaScript var in a link

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, var

I found the JavaScript to break up the queryString of a page and pull a variable from it.  I needed to do this so that I could create a new link that would put the website into a facebook app I am trying.  Basically, we upload pages to our server which generates a long value (k).  So, the URL is always www.oursite.com/webhost/login.asp?k=12342342334 etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function querySt(ji) {
    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
    var SurveyKey = querySt("k");
    var url = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/k=" + SurveyKey;
    window.location = url;
}
```

So, I have a var called "url" which should give the correct URL for what I need it to do (basically just sets the page in a facebook canvas).  I seem to be lost on how to make create a link for this.

It needs to be a button that someone clicks and it just opens a new window with the var url.  What am I missing here?  I tried

```
document.write="<a href="url...
```

but I can't reference that variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not use PHP for it instead of Javascript? If you extract the variable from the URL in PHP you can just make the link:

```
<a href="www.oursite.com/webhost/login.asp?k=<?=$your_key?>">test</a>
```

If you want to do it in javascript:

```
var url;
function querySt(ji) {
    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
    var SurveyKey = querySt("k");
    url = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/k=" + SurveyKey;

    insertInPage();
}

function insertInPage() {
    var content = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">link</a>"
    document.write(content);
    // or:   document.getElementById("your_id").innerHtml = content;
}
```

Something along those lines at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write="<a href="url...
```

… isn't valid syntax. If you want to use `document.write` to pass your url variable out to a web page as a link, you should do something like this:

```
document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">YOUR LINK TEXT</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
$('#someDiv').append('<a href="' + url + '">click here</a>');
```

Or without it:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">click here</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a link in the page and hook up a javascript function to the click event on that link.  In the JS handler for the click event, you can run whatever Javascript code you want, construct the link you want, use window.open to open a new window with that link.

Using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">Click here</a>
```

JS:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

jsfiddle here to see it in action or play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/AKuXG/

Or, if you can compute the desired link just once and set it forever, you can do that with this plain JS after the page has loaded:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").href = whatever javascript expression you want
```